# How does WPF determine what property to set when setting the content of elements in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I hope my title is clear....

What I mean is for exmaple when we define animation:

Xaml:

```
<StoryBoard>
    <DoubleAnimation..../>
</StoryBoard>
```

But if we defines same thing in code-behind, we could do:

```
DoubleAnimation myDAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
.....
StoryBoard myStoryBoard = new StoryBoard();
myStoryBoard.Children.Add(myDAnimation);
```

I tried to look into StoryBoard's class definition, nothing special:

```
public sealed class Storyboard : Timeline
{
        public Storyboard();

        // Summary:
        //     Gets the collection of child System.Windows.Media.Animation.Timeline objects.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The collection of child System.Windows.Media.Animation.Timeline objects.
        //     The default is an empty collection.
        public TimelineCollection Children { get; }
....
}
```

I know if I defines my own class with the above sytnax, in order to add into my Children, I would need to:

XAML:

```
<MyClass>
   <MyClass.Children>
      <MyClassCildrenItem..../>
   </MyClass.Children>
</MyClass>
```

So how did the Xaml knows the `DoubleAnimation` is should add into `StoryBoard`'s `Children` property?
If I need to do the same thing, what do I need to declare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an attribute for that: [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx)

If you check the `Syntax` section of classes on MSDN you can see what properties will be set when specifying content. E.g. the [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) targets the `Content` property.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I see.  I always thought that's something do with the constructor.  Didn't know it would be attribute... That's why those Button etc controls I can simply defines another control within their definition. +1 (need 3 min to accept answer again...)

Answer (score 1):

[TimelineGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timelinegroup.aspx) an ancestor of `Storyboard` has the `Children` property and it also has the [ContentPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx) which specifies the `Children` property as the content property.